# Tape instead of soldering?

Tags: soldering

I have this Polycom conference phone and the plug came off when someone tried to plug in the battery. It looks like it was kept in place with some kind of double sided tape instead of solder.

I can't really solder, so I wanted to redo the tape, but could you advise what kind of tape should I buy?

Picture attached. [image]

Comment: VTC - While the issue you posted about seems interesting it is still off topic here due to being about repair of a device.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Not that interesting. Nothing to do with tape. The copper simply delaminated from the PCB. Nothing to do here. Dead. End of.

Comment: It was soldered, indeed.

Comment: It looks like the glue may have just been used to hold the connector in place while soldering.  The PCB still looks OK, so maybe the connector could be resoldered.

Answer (score 1):

Repair questions are considered off topic however I'll split a hair and pretended that this is about PCB and product manufacturing rather than repair...

That's not tape, it's copper plating.

The connector was soldered and the solder joints were stronger than the PCB. when the connector came off it pulled the copper off of the PCB.

Normally this means the product is dead, once a PCB is physically damaged it's game over.
Sometimes if you glue the connector back down and add wires from the connector back to the undamaged part of the tracks you can get it working again but but it depends on the extent of the damage and isn't normally easy to do or reliably.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic and thanks for answering anyway!